# XSLT to XML output sorting Issue

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

When I try this, my data sorts, but the XML tags are stripped out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
 <xsl:template match="searchResults/searchResult">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:sort select="//TSN" order="descending"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I do this, the XML output format is correct, but it does not sort.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:sort select="//TSN" order="descending"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <info><statusCode>0</statusCode><messages/></info>
    <search>
        <options><maxMatches>100</maxMatches><units>m</units></options>
        <resultsCount>3</resultsCount>
        <totalPages>1</totalPages>
        <searchResults>
            <searchResult>
                <resultNumber>1</resultNumber>
                <fields>
                    <LocationState>OK</LocationState><TSN>N</TSN><LocationCity>TULSA</LocationCity>
                </fields>
            </searchResult>
            <searchResult>
                <resultNumber>2</resultNumber>
                <fields>
                    <LocationState>OK</LocationState><TSN>Y</TSN><LocationCity>BIXBY</LocationCity>
                </fields>
            </searchResult>
            <searchResult>
                <resultNumber>3</resultNumber>
                <fields>
                    <LocationState>OK</LocationState><TSN>N</TSN><LocationCity>COWETA</LocationCity>
                </fields>
            </searchResult>
        </searchResults>
        <origin><adminArea3 type="State">OK</adminArea3></origin>
    </search>
</response>
```

Any ideas? I am new to XSLT and am struggling.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: One idea might be to include the XML you're running this on. :)

Comment: I've added some sample XML.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the 'stripping out of tags' you need to read up on [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) within XSLT. These are templates that are used should you not have a specific template matching a node within your XSLT. The built-in template will output the text of a node if it is a text node (or attribute), otherwise it will just skip over the node and continue looking for templates that match the child nodes.

In your first XSLT, the only template you have matches **searchResults/searchResult** so this is the only element that will be copied. All other nodes will be matched by the built-in template, and so only text, and not the elements themselves, will be output.

In your second XSLT, the template matches **node()** which will obviously match any node. Thus the **xsl:copy** will be used for all nodes it matches to output them.

As for the sorting, this is to do with the XPath expression you are using

```
<xsl:sort select="//TSN" order="descending"/>
```

When the Xpath expression starts with a forward slash, this means it will be an absolute path, starting from the top-level document node. When you have two forward slashes, it will be searching for the node at any level under the top level document node. In other words, the expression is not relative to the child nodes of the **searchResult** element you are selecting; it will also return the value of the first **TSN** element in the XML. Therefore, as the sort is selecting the same value for each child, no sorting is done.

As for what the correct expression should be, that's not possible to say without seeing your input XML, but as a guess it might just be this...

```
<xsl:sort select="TSN" order="descending"/>
```